# Dividing a geographical area (bbox) into smaller equal sized square miles

Tags: postgis, openlayers

I'm working on an automated system for processing geographical information by bbox using PostGIS with an Openlayers 3 UI.  The user will use dragbox to 'draw' the bbox they want processed. The catch is the area can be no longer than 2 sq miles.  Is there a method for dividing up a bbox into equally sized smaller bbox's that are no larger than 2 sq miles?

Comment: Is this a Postgis or an OpenLayers question. You have tagged it as Postgis, but you seem to be asking about drawing on the client?

Comment: I have added OL3 tag, as I suspect that is what OP means.

Comment: Openlayers-3!  I'm using dragbox to select the region for a processing job.